# Make ssh LocalCommand set GNU-screen window title only when used interactively?

Tags: bash, ssh, gnu-screen, rename, title

#### Setup

I run screen on a local machine and use different screen windows to connect to different hosts. It would be nice to change window names to the host names automatically during the ssh process.

#### Approaches

I have tried different variations of the 2 approaches below:

1) Using `LocalComand` in ssh config file:

```
Host *
PermitLocalCommand yes
LocalCommand '[ "${TERM:0:6}" == "screen" ] && printf "\ek@%h\e\\"
```

2) Creating a custom bash function:

```
# function to set screen name based on host and reset on exit
function ssh() {
  echo -e '\033k'@$1'\033\\'
  ssh -Y "$@"
  echo -e '\033k'local'\033\\'
}
```

#### Problem

Both of these approaches work but they also seem to interfere with things like auto-completion:

```
$ scp user@host:~/.s<tab>
...o^[\\\\   ...cal^[\\\\
```

#### Question

Is there some condition that could be used (on top of checking if `$TERM == screen`) that would allow executing the `LocalCommand` (or the `ssh()` function) only when connecting to host and not when used for auto-completion?

Comment: Is your problem like [problem1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14113/is-it-possible-to-set-gnome-terminals-title-to-userhost-for-whatever-host-i) or like [problem2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40830/fix-terminal-title-after-ssh-remote-logging-to-another-machine/341277)?

Comment: @harrymc it's both - I want to both set the title when on ssh, and reset after closing. I did achieve it (the `function ssh() {` is very similar to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/341277/404497)). **The problem** I have is that those solutions interfere with autocomplete. i.e. they attempt to set titles even when I run commands (without logging in) via ssh, and pollute the prompt.

Comment: Note: the `PS1` way of doing this didn't work for me because after ssh'ing to a host, the prompt of that host will attempt to modify the GNU-screen window title ON that host, not the title of my local screen instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to print these control sequences, so `screen` captures them; still you must not print them to the stdout of `ssh`. **Print them to stderr.** The completion functions that use `ssh` should capture and use the output only, they should ignore error messages. But when you use `ssh` normally, `screen` will get stdout and sterr from `ssh`.

Your function modified:

```
# function to set screen name based on host and reset on exit
function ssh() {
  echo -e '\033k'@$1'\033\\' >&2
  command ssh -Y "$@"
  echo -e '\033k'local'\033\\' >&2
}
```

<sup>Note I added the word `command`. Without it the function would call itself recursively.</sup>

The above function relies on `$1` being the hostname or so. In general it may not be a case. More robust solution is to change one way using `LocalCommand` and its `%h`, then change back to `local` using a function.

```
Host *
PermitLocalCommand yes
LocalCommand exec bash -c '[ "${TERM:0:6}" == "screen" ] && printf "\ek@%h\e\\" >&2' ssh-bash
```

<sup>I forced `bash` to handle the command because `${TERM:0:6}` is not portable. `LocalCommand` uses the user's shell which in general may not support the syntax.</sup>

```
# function to reset screen name on exit
function ssh() {
  command ssh "$@"
  echo -ne '\033klocal\033\\' >&2
}
```

<sup>I removed `-Y` from the function. Now it's safe to provide it as an argument if needed.</sup>

In case printing to stderr interferes with anything else, consider printing directly to `/dev/tty` (`printf … >/dev/tty`). This has its own subtleties though.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Very nice and detailed answer, unexpected after a week of silence but very welcome.